# I'm not getting Refresh token in LinkedIn oauth 2.0 while i'm authenticating. Can anyone explain?

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I'm Integrating LinkedIn to my app, but I'm not getting `refresh_token` key. Without `refresh_token` how can I get new `access_token`. I'm getting the following response.

```
{
"access_token":"...",
"expires_in":...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i have also received only access_token,

```
{
    "access_token": "AQUe7HlT2WWW3OFqY9fOx4prW8zsdx8sN4Q8fEQJ5mIbSnuH2T94AawLB6xsOsW5Yq67mG3qmOVi2pniSHTUZcskxN91zasasdasdsdxRryFx3q9Tm_7ysV2Vmi2BFpvbMBeG16xVuHtM5dF_gPVPqVZ86gx6M4M_8EwFBOnpm-WLBasdasdasddsNA6RR1O4yoHE9G9JBX9FGJ1wHdt6WLcI1UK3CKs96X9uKxADy7AN7aeInnXzHaEzTN8iDZ9UuyHZq_QkRrtAPIec_TTC6J2Q44LsYUpA8Ooa7AUnjURLQXU4ZG4P5CAD_WtqG3x0SVPvcClbXbvnBL7iQZ-np5XJNn1bVfUzGUheGUWCiA6MKt9mQ",
    "expires_in": 5184000
}
```

if you look at their documentation you would find something like this mentiooned below, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow

"Refresh Access Token" != "Refresh Token"

However, the site also has the following mentioned regarding refresh_token

"LinkedIn has introduced Refresh Tokens with OAuth 2.0.  This feature is currently available for a limited set of partners. It will be made GA in the near future."

So, i think you have write a mail asking for your app to be approved until they would rollout a GA on for this feature.